# Getting "This type of page is not served", How to run classic asp in VisualStudio on local machine?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, asp-classic

I have an ASP.NET project in Visual Studio and have added a classic asp forum application.  When I run this on my localhost machine (XP Pro with IIS), I get "This type of page is not served because it has been explicitly forbiidden".

This project has both ASP.NET and the classic ASP both running in the same project.

How can I configure my machine and/or Visual Studio project to run the asp application?

This application runs fine on our web server but I need to modify it and debug on localhost.

Thank you,

James

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did and it worked perfectly:

http://blogs.msdn.com/greggm/archive/2006/03/15/552108.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't enabled classic ASP (it's disabled by default).

On XP 64 you would need to go into Web Service Extensions under IIS Manager and set "Active Server Pages" to "Allowed".

On XP 32 it's a bit different (since it runs an earlier version of IIS) - I think you have to play with the ISAPI Filters tab in Website properties, but I can't check that right now.

Comment: I am XP 32...  Will take a look.

Comment: I don't see what to do in ISAPI Filters.  I can't find anything for web service extensions.  I have IIS version 5.1

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run ASP from the Developement Web Server (also known as Cassini) provided with Visual Studio.  This server does not support classic ASP.

You will need to configure your IIS server to handle the web site.  You can then debug by attaching to the appropriate DLLHOST.EXE process instance.

Comment: Will I be able to run in in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter:  No you will still need to host a classic ASP site in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and found that switching the IIS 6 Isolation mode fixed it.

In Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager, right click 'Web Sites' -> Service -> Uncheck 'Run WWW service in IIS 5.0 isolation mode'